# Make_flaggable method 'flaggings' returns Stack Level Too Deep error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a 'like' button on a collection/product in my app based on this tutorial: http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/create-a-like-or-1-button-with-make_flaggable/

I can follow it great, and it works great with the liking of items by users and the unliking with the button toggle helper method, etc.

However, I want to be able to show how many 'likes' a collection/product has, and based on the Readme it ought to be the method 'flaggings'. So for e.g, for the first collection it ought to be:

```
Collection.first.flaggings
```

However, I get an error:

```
Collection Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "collections".* FROM "collections" LIMIT 1
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    from /Users/Jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80
Maybe IRB bug!
```

I've tried googling and search for an answer on stackoverflow, etc but to no avail. I do understand that the Stack Level too deep error is due to a recursive/looping call? But I'm not sure how this applies to it here.

Would appreciate any help!

Edited with code from app:

Routes.rb

```
showing collections and 'like'
  resources :collections do
    member do
     get 'like'
  end
end
```

Collection.rb

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :description, :image, :remote_image_url
belongs_to :user
has_many :products,     dependent: :destroy
has_many :events,       dependent: :destroy
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
make_flaggable :like


validates :name,        presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }
validates :image,       presence: true 
validates :user_id,     presence: true
end
```

Partial section of users.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :user_bio, 
                :shop, :cover_photo, :avatar, :remote_image_url
has_secure_password
mount_uploader :cover_photo, ImageUploader
mount_uploader :avatar, ImageUploader

make_flagger

scope :shop, where(shop: true)

has_many :posts,                    dependent: :destroy
has_many :relationships,            dependent: :destroy,
                                    foreign_key: "follower_id"
has_many :reverse_relationships,    dependent: :destroy,
                                    foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                    class_name: "Relationship"

has_many :following, through: :relationships, source: :followed 
has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower 

has_many :collections,              dependent: :destroy
```

Collections_controller.rb

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate, only: [:create, :destroy]
before_filter :store_location, only: :show  
before_filter :current_collection, only: :show

def like
    @current_user = current_user
    @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])

    if @current_user.flagged?(@collection, :like)
        # User has liked it, let's UNlike it
        @current_user.unflag(@collection, :like)
        redirect_back_or root_path
        flash[:success] = "You have unliked this collection."           
    else
        # User has not like it yet, let's like it
        @current_user.flag(@collection, :like)
        redirect_back_or root_path
        flash[:success] = "You have liked this collection!"         
    end
end

def show
    @title = "Collection"
    collection_user_id = Collection.find(params[:id]).user_id
    @user = User.find(collection_user_id)
    @product = Product.new
    @products = Collection.find(params[:id]).products
    @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    @collection = current_user.collections.build(params[:collection])
    if @collection.save
        flash[:success] = "New collection added."
        redirect_to shop_user_path(current_user)
    else
        flash[:error] = "Sorry, there seems to be an error adding your collection. Why don't you try again?"
        redirect_to shop_user_path(current_user)
    end
end

def destroy
    @collection = current_user.collections.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @collection.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Collection deleted."
    redirect_to shop_user_path(current_user)
end

private

    def current_collection
        session[:collection_id] = Collection.find(params[:id]).id.to_i
    end

end
```

If you guys need anymore code, do tell me. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you paste your model. Something can be in your own code.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the mysql statement it returns. have you restarted console etc?

Comment: @shingara: pasted the model. I simply followed the instructions to add make_flagger int he user.rb model and make_flaggable, :attribute in the model that can be flagged. In this case, make_flaggable, :like for a Collection.

Thank you guys for the help!

Comment: @Isotope: Yes, I have restarted the server, console etc.
Thank you guys for the help!

Comment: I presume you've run bundle to get all the dependencies for make_flaggable? There seem to be quite a few.

Comment: Yes, I did bundle install. but how do I know which are dependencies for it? so I can double-check my gemfiles to see if I missed anything...

Comment: Same problem here. If it helps, this appeared only after upgrading from Rails 3.1 to 3.2. Did you try to contact make_flaggable devs? https://github.com/cavneb/make_flaggable